# Minor grid lines missing

Tags: inkscape

I have a page of size 210*297 mm, and I want a 1 mm grid.

So I create one, but the spacing is not 1 mm and the minor grid lines isn't showing.

Am I doing something wrong? Inkscape version is 1.0.2

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inkscape automatically hides minor grid lines when you are too far zoomed out for them to be useful. Simply zoom in until they are visible.

You can also add multiple grids with different spacing and major line values until you get the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks `:)` ....